# Limits of $\sin(z)$ and $\cos(z)$ as $z \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm faced with the following problem.

> Do the following exist in the complex plane? $$ \lim_{z\rightarrow \infty} \sin(z) \ \ \text{and} \ \  \lim_{z\rightarrow \infty} \cos(z)$$

I'll show my work for $\sin(z)$, as the work for $\cos(z)$ is the same. 
$$  \lim_{z\rightarrow \infty} \sin(z) =\lim_{z\rightarrow \infty} \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i} \\ \lim_{z\rightarrow \infty} e^{iz} = \infty \ \ , \ \lim_{z\rightarrow \infty} e^{-iz}=0 \\ \therefore =\lim_{z\rightarrow \infty} \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i} = \lim_{z\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\infty}{2i}=\infty$$

I read that infinity should be regarded as a point in the complex plane, using the example that $\infty$ is the 'top' of a sphere.  Does this imply that $ \lim_{z\rightarrow \infty} \sin(z)$ exists in the complex plane?

Thank you!

Comment: So $\lim_{z\to\infty}e^{iz}=\infty$? Not bad for a function which when restricted to the reals just goes round in a circle!

Comment: mmm, I see my mistake. Thank you

Comment: an alternative approach can be using the sequential characterization of functional limits. Then you can find easily two sequences $s_1,s_2\in\Bbb C^{\Bbb N}$ that diverge to infinity such that $(\cos(s_{1,k}))_{k\in\Bbb N}$ and $(\cos(s_{2,k}))_{k\in\Bbb N}$ converge to different limits, hence the functional limit doesnt exists.

Answer (score 6):

If you consider just the real line, both sine and cosine oscillate infinitely many times as you go to infinity. Thus, the limit cannot exist in the reals. The complex limit cannot exist if the real limit does not. In fact, both $\sin(z)$ and $\cos(z)$ have what is called an [essential singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_singularity) at complex infinity.